# jquery slideshow won't stop!

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery.cycle for slideshows. I am trying to get it to stop when my mouse leaves the designated area but the slideshow just starts up again but much slower (at regular speed without any options as if it has been called again). Anyone have any ideas of what I may be doing wrong?

```
 $('.summary').mouseenter(function(){
var vid_id=jQuery(".slideshow", this).attr('vid_id');

   jQuery(".slideshow", this).html('<img src="image_handler.php?s=002&ID='+vid_id+'" width="130" height="130"/><img src="image_handler.php?s=003&ID='+vid_id+'" width="130" height="130"/><img src="image_handler.php?s=004&ID='+vid_id+'" width="130" height="130"/><img src="image_handler.php?s=005&ID='+vid_id+'" width="130" height="130"/>');
         jQuery(".slideshow", this).cycle({
        fx: 'fade',
        speed: 500,
        timeout:500
    });
  }),
$(function(){
  $('.summary').mouseleave(function(){                           
      jQuery(".slideshow", this).cycle('stop'); 
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling 'destroy' on mouseleave instead, this will stop the slideshow and unbind all events.

Comment: Thanks Clayton, however the stupid thing just starts up again.

Comment: Clayton, it was because I was using the 'lite' version of the plugin. I just used the next one up and it is working now. You can have the answer since you are the only one who suggested something.